# Whatsapp .crypt7 decrypt

Tags: c#, whatsapp

Whatsapp is change the message db to .crypt 7, and now my little app that written in c# not working now (i have a little app for myself for viewing my history chats) because it written for old crypt db of whatsapp.

Now, i see that whatsapp is useing new crypt - .crypt7 - what is it? and how i can convert it? i see also have there local key for decrypt? how i can use it with my little c# for decrypt and read it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to get encryption key. if you have root, you can copy /data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key here. As far as i know whatsapp using "aes" for encryption.